# Origine des deux prononciations de la lettre X

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, alphabet

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi la lettre `X` peut être [prononcée de deux manières](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2395) (plus quelques exceptions) :

1. [gz] comme examiner, exercer, exécuter ...
2. [ks] comme axe, fixe...

D'où viennent ces prononciations ?

Comment: La lettre Z peut être prononcée de trois façons (au moins à ma connaissance) : /gz/ /ks/ et /s/.

Comment: Les consonnes des paires sonores/sourdes (b/p, d/t, g/k, v/f, z/s, j/ch) se transforment facilement l'une en autre en fonction du contexte.

Comment: C'est probablement le même type de raison qui explique que le S se prononce [z] entre deux voyelles, même si la règle n'est pas la même.

Comment: Dans tes exemple on a [gz] devant les voyelles et [ks] en fin de mot. Ça marche aussi devant les consonnes sourdes *extermination* [ks] (curieusement pas de x + consonne sonore en français). La raison est une assimilation rétrograde de la sonorisation. Si quelqu'un a le courage de mettre ça en forme pour une réponse avant moi, que ce quelqu'un le fasse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On prononce [gz] dans les mots commençant par `ex-` suivi d'une voyelle, ainsi que dans leurs composés. On prononce aussi [gz] dans les mots construits sur le préfixe `hexa-`. Avec le préfixe `sexa-`, on trouve les deux prononciations.

- examiner = [ɛɡzamine]
- exercer = [ɛɡzɛʁse]
- exiger = [ɛɡziʒe]
- exonérer = [ɛɡzɔneʁe]
- exulter = [ɛɡzylte]
- hexagone = [ɛɡzagon]
- sexagénaire = [sɛksaʒenɛʁ] ou [sɛgzaʒenɛʁ]

Si le `x` n'est pas suivi d'une voyelle, et dans les mots qui ne sont pas construits sur ces préfixes, on prononce [ks].

- extra = [ɛkstʁa]
- expansif = [ɛkspɑ̃sif]
- taxi = [taksi]
- annexe = [anɛks]
- lexique = [lɛksik]
- vexer = [vɛkse]

---

Après beaucoup de recherches, j'ai trouvé l'origine de cette division entre `ks` et `gz`.

La lettre X en français vient de la lettre latine, `X`, qui a toujours le son [ks] après une voyelle (avec quelque exceptions, qui ne sont pas pertinentes pour la division entre [ks] et [gz]). La lettre X en latin vient du grec ancien et ses dialectes. La forme de la lettre vient de la lettre grecque chi (χ) et le son vient de la lettre étrusque chi, qui a le son de la lettre grecque, xi (ξ).  Donc, à l'origine, la lettre `X` avait toujours le son [ks] après une voyelle en français, comme en latin.

La raison pour laquelle [ks] est devenu [gz] est très compliquée, mais c'est à cause d'un "s-drop". [Voir ici pour l'explication (section 1.1).](http://books.google.ca/books?id=9rJiC1gP_0wC&lpg=PA187&ots=jZD0mc_Ro6&dq=&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false) Essentiellement, en quelques mots, le son [s] dans `ex` était redondant. Par exemple : `exemple` est une combinaison des racines `ex-` et `-sample`. Donc il y a deux `s` : `eks` + `sample`. Dans ce cas, le `s` devient un son [z], puis la succession de consonnes devient [gz] (à cause de l'accent tonique, qui change avec ce "s-drop").

Un peu compliqué, mais il faut lire la section du livre que j'ai donné comme lien.

Comment: C'est exact pour ce qui est du préfixe ex-. Par contre quand le mot ne commence pas par ex- la prononciation est toujours  [ks] (*texte, axe*). Pour ex- tu peux ajouter le cas du h qui suit le X en milieu de mot et qui ne change rien puisqu'il est muet, et surtout la prononciation [z] dans les ordinaux (*deuxième, sixième, dixième* et leurs dérivés).

Comment: Le X se prononce [gz] seulement dans les préfixes `ex-` et `hex-` (et les composés comme *coexister*) lorsqu'ils sont suivis d'une voyelle ou d'un H muet, ainsi qu'en début de mot (*xylophone*). On prononce [ks] ailleurs (*vexer* [vɛkse]), sauf en finale (muette) et dans les composés de *deux*, *six*, *dix* et certains noms propres. Mais tout ceci n'explique pas **l'origine** de cette variation, qui est l'objet de la question.

Comment: @Lamloumi je voudrais dire que Gilles a raison. J'ai pas expliqué l'origine de la variation, mais même vous avez choisi mon réponse comme "accepted answer". Vous ne devriez pas le faire encore. Je vais chercher cette origine. Si je le trouve, vous devriez le choisir. Si je ne le trouve pas, j'offrirais un 'bounty' pour votre question parce que je pense qu'elle est importante.

Comment: À noter que dans certaines régions (Québec) le x se prononce gz devant d'autres lettres. Ici la plupart des gens prononcent augzilliaire (pour auxiliaire), par exemple. Je me suis engueulé avec une prof de linguistique à l'université à ce propos, qui m'affirmait que ma façon de prononcer était incorrecte. Texas est souvent prononcé aussi avec quelque chose entre le gz et le ks (Tegksas)sous l'influence de l'anglais.