# Prononciation de la liaison après « grand »

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

J'ai remarqué que plusieurs des personnes que je connais ainsi que moi prononceraient cette phrase :

> C'est un grand homme. *(Grand comme grandiose)*

Comme ceci (je prononce un t lié entre *grand* et *homme*):

> <del>C'est un grand-**t**-homme</del>.

Est-ce commun?

Si oui, d'où cette liaison provient-elle?

Comment: C'est une liaison parfaitement habituelle. [Liaisons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28linguistique%29).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bien, au moins je n'ai pas inventé de toute pièce cette liaison. Mais ma deuxième question reste : D'où le "*t*" provient-il? Pourquoi ne prononçons-nous pas [gʁɑ̃d‿ ɔm]?

Comment: Les consonnes des paires sonores/sourdes (b/p, d/t, g/k, v/f, z/s, j/ch) se transforment facilement l'une en autre en fonction du contexte.  Pour un autre exemple, voir http://french.stackexchange.com/q/11152/176, pour des détails techniques, attendre Evpok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le glissement /d/ → /t/ fait partie de ce qu'on appelle en linguistique le « relâchement articulatoire », ou loi du moindre effort<sup>1</sup> : ce qui est  difficile à articuler est automatiquement simplifié quand c'est possible et que le sens est conservé.

Dans

> Un grand homme
>   [œ̃.ɡʁɑ̃.tɔm]

nous sommes face à un phénomène d'[amuïssement](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amu%C3%AFssement) d'une consonne sonore finale en une consonne sourde finale.

Mais l'amuïssement peut se faire dans le sens sourde → sonore, tout dépend de ce qui requiert le plus/le moins d'effort dans la réalisation de la prononciation. Par exemple /f/ → /v/ :

> Il est neuf heures 
>   [il.ɛ.nœv‿œʁ]

Ou pour reprendre l'exemple de  jlliagre le cas du  /s/ → /z/

> Trois agneaux.
>   [tʁwɑ.z‿a.ɲo/]

Cette liaison par glissement du /d/ vers /t/ est obligatoire de nos jours dans le cas que tu cites car conserver le son /d/ pour la liaison rendrait  :
 [œ̃.ɡʁɑ̃.dɔm] (on ne parlerait plus d'un homme qui a pour caractéristique d'être grand, mais d'un « grand » appartenant à un homme).

<sup>1</sup> [Introduction à la phonétique historique du français](http://books.google.fr/books?id=GB1VxSeE1r4C&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=phon%C3%A9tique+%22loi+du+moindre+effort%22&source=bl&ots=neCzYGYJPD&sig=OM6CcyOp8Cx6aL36RvhZ10mExbc&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=07DXU4m2JaPe7AaagoHgBA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=phon%C3%A9tique%20%22loi%20du%20moindre%20effort%22&f=false) p.17

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la réponse très détaillé explicant le sujet nébuleux du "relâchement articulatoire".

Answer (score 1):

Les liaisons suivant un *D* se font comme s'il s'agissait d'un *T*, de même que les liaisons suivant un *S* ou un *X* se font avec un *Z*.

Il est admis que la liaison du *D* en *T* est une survivance de l'ancien français où, par exemple dans le cas de *grand* (*un grand homme*) le masculin était ***grant*** alors que le féminin était (et est resté) *grande*. De même pour *quand* (*quand il...*) qui s'écrivait et se prononçait ***quant***.

L'orthographe a aligné plus tard *grand* sur son étymologie, mais le français parlé a conservé dans la liaison la prononciation ancienne.

Pour ce qui est de la liaison de *fond en comble*, on rencontrait plusieurs graphies pour ***fond*** : *fons*, *fonz* et ***font*** et c'est la troisième qui a été préservée dans la prononciation.

Answer (score 0):

Certains mots comme *petit* se terminent par une consonne muette. Parfois à l'oral cette consonne est en relation avec la voyelle (ou au h muet) qui débute le mot suivant. c'est ce qui s'appelle une liaison.

> Petit enfant, se dit : Peti tenfant

On a trois types de liaisons : **Obligatoire, Interdite et facultative**. (plein d'exemples sur le net)

Dans ton cas on est dans une liaison obligatoire entre un adjectif et le nom. Dans le même ton, on trouve :

> Un gros avion va décoller. De jeunes enfants.

Qui se prononce :

> Un gro zavion va décoller. De jeune zenfants.

Comment: Mais "grand" se termine avec un *d*, les examples que tu as écrites représentent la liaison de mots selon la dernière lettre du mot précédent. Ce qui est parfaitement normal. Si on se fit à ce que tu viens d'écrire, il faudrait prononcer : "*C'est un gran d'homme*". Ce n'est pas le cas ici.

Comment: C'est la même chose avec grand qui est un adjectif et donc se comporte de la même manière. J'aurai pu dire un grand enfant qui se pronnonce un gran tenfant...

Comment: Mais pourquoi le *d* se prononcerait soudainement comme un *t*? Le *s* possède déjà la prononciation *z*, mais le *d* se prononce toujours *d*. Vois-tu ce que je veux dire?

Comment: The word was both pronounced and spelled "grant" in older French. If it were still spelled that way, this liason would be obvious.  However, spelling was latinised to "grand" to match other words with same root like "grandiose". It is historical spelling revision, not really a linguistic phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le Seigneur des anneaux, quand ils parlent d'emmener l'anneau au Mordor durant la réunion à Foncombe, Boromir se lève et dit « Blablabla... et le grand-(t)œil ...blablabla. » C'est ce que je donne toujours comme exemple dans ces cas où des gens me traitent de débile et qu'il faut passer par ce genre de site pour leur faire comprendre... Merci d'être là T_T

Comment: Cette réponse n'apporte rien de plus à la question posée voilà 5 ans... Les exemples de cette liaison sont légion et la réponse acceptée explique clairement le comment du pourquoi...

Answer (score 0):

Apparemment le /t/ de /œ̃ɡʁɑ̃tɔm/ ou de /gʀãtõkl/ est la survivance et résurgence dans ce contexte de liaison du dévoisement en position finale des occlusives sonores, phénomène opérant en ancien français et bien connu dans certaines langues comme l'allemand ou le russe :

- Weg /ve:k/, chemin
- рад /rat/, content

L'article sur le dévoilement final de Wikipédia en parle :

> L'ancien français connaissait le dévoisement final, qui n'était que parfois noté graphiquement. Il se remarque notamment dans la dérivation lexicale :
>
> corp ou corb ~ corbel (« corbeau » dans les deux cas)
>
> vert ~ verdoier
>
> lonc ou long ~ longuet
>
> nuef ~ novel (« neuf » ~ « nouveau »)
>
> crois ~ croisier (« croix » ~ « croiser »)
>
> Le dévoisement final a disparu du français moderne, à la suite de la chute de la plupart des anciennes consonnes finales et à l'amuïssement du e caduc, qui a exposé toute une série de nouvelles consonnes en finale, sourdes comme sonores. Il en reste cependant quelques traces dans l'alternance morphologique de f et v (par exemple entre *neuf* et *neuve*, *vif* et *vive*) et dans la liaison, lorsqu'elle fait réapparaître d'anciennes occlusives, lesquelles demeurent sourdes (par exemple avec une liaison [t] dans ***grand homme***, *prend-il* et marginalement dans la liaison en [k], aujourd'hui obsolète comme dans *sang impur*, *long article* dans une diction traditionnelle). En revanche, les fricatives sont sonores en liaison, qu'il s'agisse de la liaison courante en [z] (*gros homme*, *deux enfants*) ou de celle rare en [v] dans certaines expressions figées (*neuf heures*, *neuf ans*). Dans la prononciation de *six* et *dix*, le [s] sourd final à la pause se sonorise en [z] en liaison.

Certains attribuent le phénomène à une influence du vieux-francique sur l'ancien français.